# how to add edit parameter for power bi iframe embedding

Tags: powerbi

I have a basic HTML iframe embed code, would like to include the edit parameter so that the users can the edit and save the embedded dashboards

My sample code

```html
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
   <h2>Contoso Retail Worldwide Report</h2>
   <iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?
r=eyJrIjoi0TgzZmYzYjAtNmFiNy00MzMxLTk2YjEtMTFiMjk1YWE4MjE4IiwidCI6IjM1ZDVhYzRkLTc5YmQtNDkwYS1hYjJhLTU5MGZjZDViMzE4ZiIsImMiOjF9" 
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```